# apt-get update <<NOSPLIT>> obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)

Tags: ubuntu, update

tengo este pequeño detalle y no se que pueda ser :S alguna idea para actualizar con proxy, creo que mi proveedor de internet tiene bloqueado estas direcciones (no sestoy seguro), se los agradeceria.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sistemas# sudo apt-get update
Des:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [2 665 B]
Err:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Des:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [2 672 B]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Des:3 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [2 673 B]
Err:3 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Des:4 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [2 675 B]
Err:4 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Descargados 10.7 kB en 0s (31.4 kB/s)
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: Fallo al obtener http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

Comment: Hola. Prueba esta idea de solución: Instala **Gdebi** con el gestor de sofware de ubuntu. Acto seguido entra al repositorio de ubuntu [Ubuntu packages search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) y descargas el paquete. Le pides a Gdebi que lo instale desde el archivo descargado. Gdebi lo instala resolviendo todas las dependencias

Comment: A xenial le quedan menos de seis meses de soporte y 18.04 esta muy madura y estable y vivirá hasta 2023. Te sugiero moverte a ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según por mi solución, entiendo que el problema es del servidor de donde se hace la descarga mas no del paquete en si. En Fuentes de Software cambié el servidor de *EvoWise CDN*  a *ITS Telecomunicacoes*. En base también puse un servidor de Brasil.

Principal: `https://mint.itsbrasil.net/packages`

Base: `http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu`

Comment: Efectivamente. Yo lo solucioné eligiendo los espejos: Principal (Tricia) http://package.linuxmint.com Base (Bionic) http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/mint/ubuntu 21/ago/2021